# Aurelia repeat seems to erase custom properties in parent scope

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a custom attribute which adds a property to the `bindingContext` so that other custom attributes/elements can make use of this data.

So for example the attribute bind method may look like:

```
bind(binding, scope) {
    binding.someCustomProperty= this.value; // have tried using scope too
}
```

Now anything contained within the scope of this custom attribute works fine, i.e:

```
<section my-attribute="something">
    <input some-other-attribute="somethingElse">
</section>
```

So assuming the section attribute sets the `bindingContext` property, then the `some-other-attribute` would access that property on the `bindingContext` and it would all work.

However the issue comes in when I use a repeat and want to use the `some-other-attribute` within the repeat binding, the `bindingContext` loses the `someCustomProperty`. So is there a "correct" way to add to a binding context and persist through repeat or other child bindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to change your custom attribute to work like this:

```js
bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
  overrideContext.someProperty = something;
}
```

I'm suggesting you use the `overrideContext` because one of the primary reasons it exists is for storing additional "contextual" bindable props like `$event`, `$first`, `$last`, `$index` etc, without adding props to the underlying view-model.

This change alone won't resolve your issue.  What's happening is each item in the repeat has it's own bindingContext/overrideContext.  These are a hierarchy, so you could detect the "repeat" scenario by looking for [repeat-specific props](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/src/repeat-utilities.js#L59) like `$first`, `$last`, `$odd`, `$even`:

```js
bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
  // are we in a repeat?
  if ($even in overrideContext) {
    overrideContext = overrideContext.parentOverrideContext;
  }
  overrideContext.someProperty = something;
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, will give that a go, so by default do all contexts have access to their parents (as shown)?

Comment: right, when you do something like `foo.bind="bar"`, the binding system is going to look for `bar` on the overrideContext, then on the bindingContext, then on the parent overrideContext, then on the parent bindingContext, and so on.

Comment: not all contexts have access to their parents, for example a custom element will not have a parentOverrideContext.  This keeps custom elements encapsulated and portable.  They can't access the outer scope.